# How to get 64-bit support architectures libraries?

Tags: android, apk, 64-bit, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

**I added a line:**

*ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'*

**I checked lib folder:**

*I have 3 folders with the same file in folders: armeabi-v7a ; x86 ; x86_64*

**I Run: > adb install --abi armeabi-v7a YOUR_APK_FILE.apk on Pixel 3:**

*Works well*

**Google Play Console still shows:**

*The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 204.*

As I could understand I'm getting this error cause lib folder is missing *"arm64-v8a"*.

Could someone explain why this folder is not generated at all? 
Can it happen cause one of the lib do not provide 64bit support? 
Is there any way to find out which library it is?

**My dependencies screenshot image:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q716FhmbJvt8N6kkfS74qJAIGuu7nahR/view

Comment: you can check which library so file is missing by creating normal release APK, no bundle then drag that APK in your android studio and you'll see lib folder with sub folders holding these so files. See which so file is not present in all these subfolders. BTW as far as i know App bundle is supposed to handle this.

Comment: I have 3 folders and as I wrote I'am missing:arm64-v8a; Picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o6rq45M9nl0tw8AODtrZRrzeazcqg04_/view?usp=sharing; I tried with App Bundle(I thought it will fix it) still the same warning message.

Comment: these so files are there because of third party libraries or framework you may be using for eg: React native, Realm Database see which library creates so file by going to their github wiki

Comment: Thank you very much! Case completed! We were checking every lib by deleting them step by step. One of the library from the list was supporting just 32-bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this line in your gradle hope this will work for you, because your APK is already ready for 64bit devices.
Use android app bundle to publish your app.

```
ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a','x86_64'
```

Comment: nope, it didn't help. I wrote it above in my text. Bali answer was right, one of the lib didn't provide 64-bit support. After I deleted it, everything works well. Case closed.